# Pagination - Removing a large space between bottom of rows and pagination links

Tags: php, css

The pagination below works well.  It splits a table into 25 rows per page.  However, when I click on a page besides page one, there is a large space between the bottom of the 25 rows and the pagination links.  I think the problem is related to the CSS.  How can I get rid of this large space?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
/******  build the pagination links ******/  
// range of num links to show    

// if not on page 1, don't show back links  
if ($currentpage > 1) {  
   // show << link to go back to page 1  
   echo " <div class='pages'><div class='pages'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1&find={$_SESSION['find']}&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'><<</a></div> ";  
   // get previous page num  
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;  
   // show < link to go back to 1 page  
   echo " <div class='pages'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage&find={$_SESSION['find']}&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'><</a></div> ";  
} // end if   

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page  
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {  
   // if it's a valid page number...  
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {  
      // if we're on current page...  
      if ($x == $currentpage) {  
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link  
         echo " <div class='pages'>[<b>$x</b>] </div>";  
      // if not current page...  
      } else {  
         // make it a link  
     echo " <div class='pages'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x&find={$_SESSION['find']}&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>$x</a></div> ";  
      } // end else  
   } // end if   
} // end for  

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links      
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {   
   // get next page  
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;  
    // echo forward link for next page   
   echo " <div class='pages'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage&find={$_SESSION['find']}&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>></a></div> ";  
   // echo forward link for lastpage  
   echo " <div class='pages'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages&find={$_SESSION['find']}&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>>></a></div> ";  
} // end if  
/****** end build pagination links ******/
```

In case it's helpful, here is how the pagination links's generated HTML looks:

```
</table> 
 <div class='pages'><div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=1&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'><<</a></div>  <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=1&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'><</a></div>  <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=1&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>1</a></div>  <div class='pages'>[<b>2</b>] </div> <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=3&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>3</a></div>  <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=4&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>4</a></div>  <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=5&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>5</a></div>  <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=3&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>></a></div>  <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch.php?currentpage=7&find=best book ever&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>>></a></div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
.pages
    {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
    margin-top: 940px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    }       

 a.links:link {
    color: #000000; text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    }

 a.links:visited {
    color: #000000; text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    }

 a.links:active {
    color: #000000; text-decoration: none; 
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    }

 a.links:hover {
    color: #000000; text-decoration: none; 
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a live link or at least the generated HTML? It's kind of hard to guess the rendered HTML output from a raw huge PHP script.

Comment: I added the generated HTML for the links.

Comment: Actually, I think my problem might be with the CSS I'm using.  I think I will edit this question.

Answer (score 1):

You must change "<<<" and ">>>" to the proper html entities: "&lt;&lt;&lt;" and "&gt;&gt;&gt;". Your HTML is broken.

For instance, this line:

```
echo " <div class='pages'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages&find={$_SESSION['find']}&searching=yes&search=search' class='links'>>></a></div> ";
```

Should be:

```
echo " <div class='pages><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages&amp;find={$_SESSION['find']}&amp;searching=yes&amp;search=search' class='links'>&gt;&gt;</a></div> ";
```

The bad HTML is almost certainly causing the unexpected display. You can't test potential spacing issues until you have properly formed markup.

Comment: Why would using "<" instead of "&lt" cause any spacing issues?

Comment: If your HTML is malformed (using "<" is treated as the start of an HTML tag, so if you want to display a less than symbol you have to use an encoding, which in the HTML spec is &lt;) the browser will render the page unpredictably. Browsers are programmed to make certain assumption when encountering improper HTML, and the results are difficult to predict, which could easily result in problems like odd spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I see this in your pagination example:

```
<div class='pages'>
 <div class='pages'><a href='/booksearch[/snip]
```

but I don't see in your code anywhere for a  "<div class='pages'>" to be by itself??